# Get How Many Lines Were Processed During Spark Filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a basic operation - filter a dataframe / rdd.

```
val sc = ...
val seqRDD = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)

val filteredData = seqRDD.filter(v => v < 10)
... count / other actions...
```

I want to get real time statistics about how many lines have been processed already during this filter. Or, how many percentage of the filter was completed.
How can I get real time statistic?  Searched online, couldn't find a proper solution...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spark's **accumulators** for such purposes. Accumulators provide a way to update values on the worker nodes and accumulate these values on the Spark Driver. They don't provide a true "realtime" statistics, but they can definitely give you a good approximation of progress.

In this case, you can create an accumulator that simply counts the records passing through your filter:

```
// create accumulator on Driver
val counter = sc.longAccumulator("filtered")

// use it in function sent to Worker
val filteredData = seqRDD.filter { v =>
  counter.add(1)
  v < 10
}

// perform some action on filteredData...

// use accumulator's value method to get value in Driver at any given moment.
println(counter.value)
```

In the example above, we "read" the accumulator only after we're done. But you can access `counter.value` from other threads while the action on `filteredData` is still running, and get "partial" results. Here is a simple example that shows this:

```
// partitioning the data - otherwise accumulator would 
// probably only get updated for all data at once:
val seqRDD = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000, 20)

// create accumulator
val counter = sc.longAccumulator("filtered")

// schedule TimerTask to print current value of accumulator every 50 milis:
val t = new java.util.Timer()
t.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask {
  def run() = println(counter.value)
}, 10L, 50L)

// apply filter
val filteredData = seqRDD.filter { v =>
  counter.add(1)
  Thread.sleep(5)
  v < 10
}

// perform action:
filteredData.collect()

t.cancel()
```

This prints the `counter.value` while the action is running, and the output looks something like:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
200
200
200
200
200
400
400
400
400
400
450
600
600
600
600
600
700
800
800
800
800
900

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sample scenario.

Lets say I have a file and there are blank lines in it. I want to count those blank lines and filter them.

Sample File:

Hello World

This is a sample Files

Using accumulator to calculate blank lines.

Code:

```
val accum = sc.accumulator(0,"testAccum")

scala> rddFile.filter{ x =>
 | if(x == "")
 | {
 | accum += 1
 | }
 | x != ""
 | }


accum.value
```

Please collect rdd coming as a result of filter first then followed by printing value of "accum"

This will print number of blank lines available in the file. if you want to know how many rows processed just lift the if condition.